# Wondering which percentage below it we can say the classes are suffering from under-representation and need a resampling approach

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, data-mining, supervised-learning

I am sure here there is someone who has experienced something like this... I have a dataset with 4 classes, one of it is 3% representation and I considered it as under-represented, so I did some resampling approaches, but guess what? its classification accuracy didn't change except by just 1 or 2% at best over the classification accuracy without the resampling approaches! So I wonder if 3% of the class representation among the data could be considered as under-representation or not?